# face recognition using c library in linux

Tags: c, linux, image-processing, face-recognition

I have to know about face recognition library in linux. I want to do face recognition using c language in on linux plate-form. I don't want to use MATLAB. If you know any web site,library or book then please inform me. Thank You

Comment: You can check This libraries:
http://blog.mashape.com/post/53379410412/list-of-40-face-detection-recognition-apis

Answer (score 2):

The OpenCV can help you. See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/)

Answer (score 1):

Download Opencv for Linux by following the  [link](http://opencv.org/downloads.html). Read the documentation provided ,it has API's to perform Image processing .