# Facial recognition software that can detect eye positions

Tags: linux, macos, image-processing, face-recognition

I'm looking for a software API that can detect pairs of eyes in an image and return the location of them. I'm not too concerned with which programming language the API uses, just need something that I can run on a linux or mac computer in an automated way so that I can batch results to a file.

Comment: did you try google search?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327676/face-recognition-using-c-library-in-linux

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac Yes. It didn't work nearly as well as SO which got a perfect answer in a few minutes. Besides, it's hilarious how often the first hits for a question on the internet are "google it".

Comment: @user3295442 My question is more specific but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simply way is to use openCV to do that.

Look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23191/Face-and-Eyes-Detection-Using-OpenCV for sample

Answer (score 1):

I think that OpenCV is what you want. There is a module called objdetect on this lib:

From doc:

> objdetect - detection of objects and instances of the predefined
>   classes (for example, faces, eyes, mugs, people, cars, and so on).

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)